{"message":"Forbidden"} when navigate to another page for nextjs 14 app deployed to aws lambda integarted with api gateway
My frontend uses nextjs 14 with a Docker file, github actions build and push the docker image to aws ECR, cloudformation retrieve the docker image from ECR and create lambda function and its integrated api gateway. With the url from stage of api gateway, I can access the page, but when navigate to another page from e.g homepage, I got {"message":"Forbidden"} shown in the browser instead of the real page. And the same for other page i.e if I access the page via the url provided by api gateway stage, I can access the page, but if e.g I navigate to homepage, I got {"message":"Forbidden"} again.
In summary, I can only access the page via the url provided by api gateway stage, but not a page navigated from that page.
Anyone knows why and how to fix it?
after investigation, i noticed that The reason of Forbidden is because when navigating, the url lost stage name. For example, homepage url is https://abcdefg.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/prod/, when navigating to blog whose url is supposed to be https://abcdefg.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/prod/blog, but it turned to be https://abcdefg.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/blog, prod is gone.
Why stage is gone? How to fix it?

i created a simple nextjs 14 app, and use docker image to deploy to aws lambda using SAM serverless and when use HttpApi it works (see below), but when switch to use Api instead of httpApi, not working
